# Dynamically Update and Insert Records using Simple-Salesforce Library

Tags: python, simple-salesforce

I am using the Python Simple-Salesforce Library for bulk insert and updating records.

I want to create one method in which I pass the Sobject API name and then at run time have it insert/update records to that specific objects table in the Salesforce database.

Below are two examples of what I am literally looking to achieve.

Example1:

```
Sobject_Name__c = 'Case'
sf.bulk.Sobject_Name__c.insert(bulk_data, batch_size, use_serial)
```

Example2:

```
Sobject_Name__c = 'Custom_Object__c'
sf.bulk.Sobject_Name__c.insert(bulk_data, batch_size, use_serial)
```

Is there a way to dynamically insert/update objects at run time using the Simple-Salesforce Library?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Python eval statement to convert string to a method call.

See below code:

```
function_name = f"sf.bulk.{object_name}.insert"

response = eval(function_name)(bulk_data, batch_size, use_serial)

return response
```